# Extra spacing in MATLAB plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to plot some data with two y-axes, but I get a lot of extra space - as you can see in the attached image.

My code is the following; the strange thing is that the last value in `t` is `50`, not `60` like the plot would seem to show.

```
yyaxis left
plot(t,i_test*1000,'b-',t,iout*1000,'k-','LineWidth',2)
ylabel('Current (mA)')
yyaxis right
plot(t,vin,'r-','LineWidth',2)
ylabel('Voltage (V)')
xlabel('Time (s)')
```

[image]

Comment: Try `xlim([0 50]` after generating the plot?

Comment: or even `xlim([min(t), max(t)])`

Comment: or also `axis tight`

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

Adding `axis tight` like this fixed the issue.  Thanks!

```
yyaxis left
plot(t,i_test*1000,'b-',t,iout*1000,'k-','LineWidth',2)
ylabel('Current (mA)')
axis tight
```

[image]